# unix utility join and output fields

Tags: unix, join

I would like to output all fields from sorted file1 that can be joined via field1 of file1 and field2 of file2. If file1 had three fields, then I could do the following:

```
  join -1 $field1 -2 $field2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 $file1 $file2
```

But what do I do, if file1 has hundreds or thousands of fields? One of my current workarounds is Python and another is to do comm -12 on two sorted files containing the join field values from file1 and file2 and afterwards join file1 with the file generated by comm -12.

This could be the file1 **input**:

```
 1 A
 2 B
 3 C
```

And the file2 **input**:

```
 3 D
 4 E
 5 F
```

How do I get this **output** (the shared value in column 2):

```
 C
```

Without doing this:

```
 join -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.2 $file1 $file2
```

Comment: i could write it in python.the most modern unix systems has python interpreter.

Comment: OK, maybe I'll just stick with my Python solution then. I'm just surprised the unix utility join doesn't allow you to print all fields from either file1 or file2. It seems like a very obvious frequent task.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265140/37356), which uses a useful syntax. Below `n` is the number of columns.

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -o"$(echo 1.{2..n})" $file1 $file2
```